# ELF binary from memory

Tags: c, elf, file-format

I just wrote a Hello world program in C that I was playing around with. I'd like to try and dump the binary from memory(using gdb) and try to create another executable from it. I tried dumping the page with executable privileges followed by its data page; however it segfaults. Are there any approaches to doing this? Is there any way I can debug and find out why it crashes? Any generic suggestions at all?

Thanks.

[EDIT]

Its on linux and I've tried it on both 32 and 64-bit x86. The kernel version is 3.13. I set a breakpoint on _start, dumped the executable page followed by its data page to a file and tried executing it.

Comment: What exactly did you try? What platform is this on? I'm going to take a guess that it's Linux... what version of the kernel? What architecture? This is a very, very, very OS- and architecture-dependent question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is a core dump executable by itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051631/is-a-core-dump-executable-by-itself)

Comment: @DanLenski I've made an edit that replies, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Wait, are you just dumping the mapped text (exectuable page) section followed by the mapped data section to a file? That itself wouldn't be a valid ELF object, an ELF file needs an ELF header as well. I am surprised the OS even let you attempt to execute that, you should have gotten an error about an invalid ELF header or something like that.

In addition to the header, an ELF file contains many more sections that are important to be able to run it.

As for debugging, I'd start with GDB to see where it crashes. Does your program crash, or does the dynamic linker crash when trying to load your program? If the dynamic linker crashes, try debugging that, e.g. with

```
gdb --args /lib64/ld-2.18.so <your program>
```

Attempts to re-create ELF files from memory have been done before - have a look at [Statifier](http://statifier.sourceforge.net/), which even statically includes all loaded dynamic libraries into the resulting ELF.

Answer (score 1):

It might be not very simple and is certainly processor and operating system specific.

You could look at `emacs`  source `unexec.c` which is doing what you want. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10498994/841108)